# How do I test specific url crawled by google?

Tags: google-search-console, google-crawlers

On my webmaster tool looks like all links indexed, but it seems some of them not crawled by google how do I test specific url from webmaster tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log on to `search.google.com` and then to inspect a URL in your property: Enter the complete URL in the search bar at the top of any page in Search Console.

Based on that Google will send you different version of what might have happened :

- URL is on Google
- URL is on Google, but has issues
- URL is not on Google: Indexing errors
- URL is not on Google
- URL is an alt version

You can find more details on the official Google guide here about [URL Inspection Tool in search console](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9012289?hl=en)